# Search for files that begin with some letters and the search need to be non-recursive

Tags: macos, finder, search

I want to search for a file or folder in the directory I am viewing. I dont need to search recursively into sub-folders.

In Windows, if I am viewing a particular folder and want to search for files or folders that begin with the word "abc" then I type abc(not in the search box but I just type directly) and it highlights a file/folder. And then when I type "abc" again then it highlights the next file/folder that matches

Using Finder I see that only the first file/folder is highlighted. Even if I press escape and type again it only highlights the first matching file/folder. So I used the search box(command+F) to find all files/folders that begin with a particular word but this would search recursively i.e includes the sub-folders as well

I do not have files/folders sorted alphabetically in the directory that I am viewing

How can I do the search in this situation?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237237/how-to-search-mac-for-files-that-begin-or-end-with-a-space-or-period
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131806/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-items-on-the-desktop-by-typing-the-first-few-lett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command in mac OS is quite expressive, despite the fact that Apple still ships a 2011 vintage. `man find` will provide a list of all the arguments and options. There are some examples near the end of the `man` page.

N.B. this requires use of the Command Line Interface (CLI), so *open/start/launch* `Terminal.app` (*it's located in the `Utilities` folder in `Launchpad`*). If your mac OS version is Catalina or later, you'll be using `zsh` by default; otherwise your shell will be `bash`. That's largely irrelevant to the answer here, but just so you know...

I'll try to get you started based on some details in your question:

> I don't need to search recursively into sub-folders.

Use the `maxdepth` option to limit your recursion depth; `-maxdepth 1` doesn't go below the specified folder. You can go deeper by increasing `maxdepth` beyond `1`.

> want to search for files or folders that begin with the word "abc"

Use the `-name` option (or a *regular expression*) to filter the results; in this case, `-name "abc*", or if you wish the filter to be case-*insensitive* use` -iname "abc*".

The `type` option allows you to filter your results by **type**; e.g. filter *regular files* with `f`, or *directories* with `d`. If you want files or directories, you may omit this option.

Assuming the folder of interest is `/Users/YourName/YourData`, the command to use is as follows:

```shell
find /Users/YourName/YourData -iname "abc*" -maxdepth 1
```

Let us know if you have questions.

---

Some References:

1. [BSD man page for `find`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/find/)
2. [Know Your Tools: Linux (GNU) vs. Mac (BSD) Command Line Utilities](https://ponderthebits.com/2017/01/know-your-tools-linux-gnu-vs-mac-bsd-command-line-utilities-grep-strings-sed-and-find/)

Comment: Thanks. this is suitable for my need. (Would have been nice if MAC has similar functionality like Windows in this case so I can just use GUI itself)

Answer (score 1):

In Finder you can

- type `abc` (quickly) to find the first match
- use Cursor Down to move to the next file. If you keep the Shift key pressed, you select while you move

Comment: I do not have files/folders sorted alphabetically in the directory that I am viewing

Comment: @firstpostcommenter You may want to add that to your question then :-)